# HDF4 python map reader error (hdfmr.py)

Tags: python

I'm using a Python utility, HDF4MapReader, that reads an XML file generated from an HDF4 file. I think the error I'm getting may be recognized by someone who uses Python (my version is 2.6.1):

```
~/Desktop/HDF4MapReader/src$ python hdfmr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hdfmr.py", line 72, in <module>
    from Reader import Reader
  File "/Users/chuck/Desktop/HDF4MapReader/src/Reader.py", line 7, in <module>
    import XMLparser
  File "/Users/chuck/Desktop/HDF4MapReader/src/XMLparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from RIS import RIS
  File "/Users/chuck/Desktop/HDF4MapReader/src/RIS.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Image import FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM
ImportError: No module named Image
```

Line 7 from the respective modules:

line 7 from Reader.py:

```
from XMLparser import XMLparser
```

line 7 from XMLparser.py:

```
    from RIS import RIS
```

line 7 from RIS.py:

```
    from Image import FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM
```

In the directory with hdfmr.py I have RIS.py and XMLparser.py

Any ideas on what's wrong? TIA...

Comment: It doesn't look like you've posted the whole traceback.  There should be an exception listed at the bottom like `ImportError: Cannot import name FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM`

Comment: Nathan, you're psychic. Sorry, it was: ImportError: No module named Image

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of homework on the web, I discovered these errors were due to my lack of knowledge on Python basics -- I hope this will help the someone else. First, the module directory was not in my PYTHONPATH, so this fixed that issue:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/chuck/Desktop/HDF4MapReader/src
```

Next, I installed the Python Imaging Library (PIL, http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and all is now well.